# The longtable environment pushes content below it into the bottom margin of a page

Tags: tables, floats, page-breaking, longtable, pandoc

When I have two floating environments on a page (one `figure` and one `table`), the `longtable` can push the content below it into the bottom margin of the page. Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{longtable,booktabs}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\title{R Markdown v2 Demo}
\author{Li Lei \\ Han Meimei}
\date{2015/01/01}


\begin{document}
\maketitle

\lipsum


\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{foo-1}
\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{foo-2}
\caption{Two plots placed side by side.}
\end{figure}


\begin{longtable}[c]{lrrrrrrrrrrr}
\caption{A table of the first 10 rows of the mtcars
data.}\tabularnewline
\toprule
& mpg & cyl & disp & hp & drat & wt & qsec & vs & am & gear &
carb\tabularnewline
\midrule
Mazda RX4 & 21.0 & 6 & 160 & 110 & 3.90 & 2.620 & 16.46 & 0 & 1 & 4 &
4\tabularnewline
Mazda RX4 Wag & 21.0 & 6 & 160 & 110 & 3.90 & 2.875 & 17.02 & 0 & 1 & 4
& 4\tabularnewline
Datsun 710 & 22.8 & 4 & 108 & 93 & 3.85 & 2.320 & 18.61 & 1 & 1 & 4 &
1\tabularnewline
\bottomrule
\end{longtable}


\begin{table}
\caption{A Tale of Two Tables.}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rr}
\toprule
Sepal.Length & Sepal.Width\\
\midrule
5.1 & 3.5\\
4.9 & 3.0\\
4.7 & 3.2\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabular}{lrrr}
\toprule
  & mpg & cyl & disp\\
\midrule
Mazda RX4 & 21.0 & 6 & 160\\
Mazda RX4 Wag & 21.0 & 6 & 160\\
Datsun 710 & 22.8 & 4 & 108\\
Hornet 4 Drive & 21.4 & 6 & 258\\
Hornet Sportabout & 18.7 & 8 & 360\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Here is a screenshot of the second page of the PDF created from `pdflatex`:

[image: longtable problem]

If I remove the `longtable`, the text can be correctly broken onto the next page. I wonder what the problem is in this document.

```
$ pdflatex --version
pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015)
kpathsea version 6.2.1
Copyright 2015 Peter Breitenlohner (eTeX)/Han The Thanh (pdfTeX).
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the pdfTeX source.
Primary author of pdfTeX: Peter Breitenlohner (eTeX)/Han The Thanh (pdfTeX).
Compiled with libpng 1.6.17; using libpng 1.6.17
Compiled with zlib 1.2.8; using zlib 1.2.8
Compiled with xpdf version 3.04
```

## EDIT (cfr)

Here's a more minimal example demonstrating the same problem. (Could probably be pared down further: I mostly tried to eliminate packages.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{longtable}
\title{R Markdown v2 Demo}
\author{Li Lei}
\date{2015/01/01}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\lipsum

\begin{figure}
  ab
  \caption{Two plots placed side by side.}
\end{figure}

\begin{longtable}[c]{lrrrrrrrrrrr}
  \caption{A table of the first 10 rows of the mtcars
    data.}\tabularnewline
  \hline
  & mpg & cyl & disp & hp & drat & wt & qsec & vs & am & gear &
  carb\tabularnewline
  \hline
  Mazda RX4 & 21.0 & 6 & 160 & 110 & 3.90 & 2.620 & 16.46 & 0 & 1 & 4 &
  4\tabularnewline
  Mazda RX4 Wag & 21.0 & 6 & 160 & 110 & 3.90 & 2.875 & 17.02 & 0 & 1 & 4
  & 4\tabularnewline
  Datsun 710 & 22.8 & 4 & 108 & 93 & 3.85 & 2.320 & 18.61 & 1 & 1 & 4 &
  1\tabularnewline
  \hline
\end{longtable}

\begin{table}
  \caption{A Tale of Two Tables.}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{rr}
    \hline
    Sepal.Length & Sepal.Width\\
    \hline
    5.1 & 3.5\\
    4.9 & 3.0\\
    4.7 & 3.2\\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Obviously, the spilling into the right margin is expected here as I've not adapted the table to the standard text width. But the spilling into the bottom presumably is not.

[image: spill into bottom margin]

Comment: As far as I can see, the number of rows in the `longtable` is rather small. Why `longtable` then?

Comment: Because the LaTeX code for the table was generated automatically from Pandoc and Markdown, and I don't have control over what environment Pandoc uses for tables.

Comment: You can remove the dependency on `geometry` and `graphicx`.

Comment: Please roll back my edit if the example I've posted no longer reflects your intention. However, it seems to show that `longtable` alone is sufficient to create the issue. (Unless `lipsum` is to blame which seems unlikely.)

Comment: @cfr Your edit makes perfect sense. Much appreciated!

Comment: From the previous comments I collect that you want to fix the problem straight from the markdown source, without user intervention in the temporary latex file. Perhaps the right place to ask is the pandoc mailing list. Meanwhile, it may be helpful if you can show a markdown document that produces the error.

Comment: One can work around this by adding `\makeatletter
\@topnum\z@\@botnum\z@
\makeatother` just before the `figure`

Comment: @touhami can you elaborate, please?

Comment: As it is noticed by the OP the problem is due to floating in top area, one can prevent this by `\@topnum=0`(\z@ is 0) now we can noticed that the problem still if the figure go to the bottom area so `\@botnum\z@`. The conclusion (not very sure) if a longtable go in only one page, this page can't have floats in top or bottom. you can see this if you use `\begin{figure}[hbp]`

Answer (score 6):

In your markdown source code add the `\suppressfloats` command before the offending floats (tables, figures), and compile with `pandoc -f markdown+raw_tex`.

Tested on this `kantlip.md` input

```
![Two plots placed side by side.](frog.jpg)

\kant[2-3]

\suppressfloats
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{frog}
\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{frog}
\caption{Two plots placed side by side.}
\end{figure}

\begin{longtable}[c]{lrrrrrrrrrrr}
\caption{A table of the first 10 rows of the mtcars
data.}\tabularnewline
\toprule
& mpg & cyl & disp & hp & drat & wt & qsec & vs & am & gear &
carb\tabularnewline
\midrule
Mazda RX4 & 21.0 & 6 & 160 & 110 & 3.90 & 2.620 & 16.46 & 0 & 1 & 4 &
4\tabularnewline
Mazda RX4 Wag & 21.0 & 6 & 160 & 110 & 3.90 & 2.875 & 17.02 & 0 & 1 & 4
& 4\tabularnewline
Datsun 710 & 22.8 & 4 & 108 & 93 & 3.85 & 2.320 & 18.61 & 1 & 1 & 4 &
1\tabularnewline
\bottomrule
\end{longtable}

    Sepal.Length   Sepal.Width
  -------------- -------------
             5.1           3.5
             4.9           3.0
             4.7           3.2

  : A Tale of Two Tables.

\kant[17-19]
```

and with the `kantlip.txt` file

```
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
```

I compiled this example stating `pandoc -Hkantlip.txt -f markdown+raw_tex -o kantlip.pdf kantlip.md`.

Comment: Thanks! I wish I don't have to deal with this case by case. What if I add/delete some content before/after the offending floats, or move the longtable around... I certainly don't want to be in this situation: http://researchinprogress.tumblr.com/post/34692517685/changing-just-a-tiny-little-bit-in-my-latex :)

Comment: iiuc, the `\suppressfloats` is local to the current page, so that you only need to add it whenever your floats misbehave.

Comment: @Yihui you can always  use `\suppresfloats[t]` immediately after `\end{longtable}` as you never want a floating table entered after the table to "float back" before or into the table. (you should probably give erreka the bounty:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Are you sure it is **only after** `\end{longtable}`, and not **also before** `\begin{figure}`?

Comment: @erreka reasonably sure:-)

Comment: @erreka the issue with the float before the longtable is different, that one should be allowed to print not suppressed, but may need the patch in the comments under wipet's answer.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that you need not the long tables breakable to the pages but your preprocessor uses this marking for all tables. In such case, you can define longtable as normal table. It means, don't load longtable package, i.e don't use `\usepackage{longtable}` but define this:

```
\newenvironment{longtable}[2][c]
   {\table[h]
    \bgroup \def\caption##1{\omit\gdef\captiontext{##1}}
    \ifx c#1\centering\fi \ifx l#1\raggedright\fi \ifx r#1\raggedleft\fi
    \tabular{#2}
   }
   {\endtabular
    \egroup
    \ifx\captiontext\undefined \else
       \caption{\captiontext} \global\let\captiontext=\undefined \fi
    \endtable
   }
```

The problem is that LaTeX's longtable implementation cannot be combined with inserts (floats in LaTeX terminology), because it uses its own special `\output` routine for buffering.

If you really needs to combine inserts with long tables breakable to the pages then you can be inspired by [my implementation of long tables for plain TeX](http://petr.olsak.net/opmac-tricks-e.html#ltable2). It works with inserts together because it doesn't use special `\output` routine. But this is another story, because this isn't LaTeX.

**Edit** If you need to have the caption before the table, then you can define:

```
\newenvironment{longtable}[2][c]
   {\table[h]
    \setbox0=\vbox\bgroup \def\caption##1{\omit\gdef\captiontext{##1}}
    \ifx c#1\centering\fi \ifx l#1\raggedright\fi \ifx r#1\raggedleft\fi
    \tabular{#2}
   }
   {\endtabular
    \egroup
    \ifx\captiontext\undefined \else 
       \caption{\captiontext}\par\medskip \global\let\captiontext=\undefined \fi
    \unvbox0 
    \endtable
   }
```

Comment: not related. Isn't better if the caption go before the tabular?

Comment: @touhami IMHO, it is related. I've added the alternative right now.

Comment: Thanks! That is very helpful. Originally I was looking for a fix using LaTeX instead of TeX, but the comment "LaTeX's longtable implementation cannot be combined with inserts" has largely solved my puzzle. Even if the answer is "No, this is not possible", I'd still consider it a valid answer.

Comment: @Yihui Not really, You can not have floats within a longtable (but you shouldn't want that) but floats on the page that starts or ends the longtable should work (they don't always, but that's a bug) this particular one is related to this (but not fixed by the patch there) http://www.latex-project.org/cgi-bin/ltxbugs2html?pr=tools/3512

Comment: @DavidCarlisle As you mentioned, the second document in the OP doesn't work although the patched longtable.sty is used (from the patch mentioned by you). Because the whole longtable.sty is conceptually bad and the patch solves fragile parts by another fragile parts. I have studied the longtable.sty yesterday because of this thread and I have experimented with `\pagegoal`, of course. The problem is deeper than the patch.

Comment: @wipet yes:-) parts of longtable are definitely suboptimal (it is _very_ old code, older than latex2e) but at least it does address many real world use cases unlike some simple plain based macro sets I could mention:-) part of the problem not addressed by the patch is the second float floating "back" to the top of the page, that's addressed by `\suppressfloats[t]` as noted in the other answer.

Comment: This "solution" actually turns all longtables into short ones, thus disabling the ability to make tables that may span through several pages automatically, which I guess was the original intention of the Pandoc developers, so that the markdown users wouldn't have to worry about the size of their tables. And more than that, it assumes that the coder is editing LaTeX source code directly, while I understand they are editing Markdown and expecting an automatic conversion seamless.

Comment: @erreka It is fairly easy for me to use LaTeX table+tabular automatically instead of longtable even for the Markdown output, since I'm in the R Markdown world, and I can decide if I want a Markdown table or a LaTeX table from R. This is unlikely to be a blocking issue for me, but I was asking the question just in case some day I do need a longtable. If the issue can be fixed, good, otherwise it does not really hurt me at the moment. It is good to know `\suppressfloats`. Thanks!

Comment: Pandoc uses control sequences like `\endfirsthead`, `\endhead` and so forth, which error when I remove the `logntable` package to replace the env with this one. What can I do about this?

Answer (score 0):

1.In between longtable `\end{table}` and `\lipsum` command use `\pagebreak` command

2.Use minipage environment as shown below:

```
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5 \linewidth}
\begin{tabular*}{0.9 \textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}rr}
```

and

```
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.5 \linewidth}
\begin{tabular*}{0.9 \textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}lrrr}
```

and end with `\end{tabular*}` in both tabular* environments.3. To separate the long table and minipage tables you can use `\vspace{2cm}` command so that the `\lipsum` will start on third page. The idea is to separate the table and running matters so as to get the correct page breaks at the bottom.

Comment: I fixed you wiki markup (you can not use `\\ `to get `\ `) but it isn't clear that this answer addresses the question at all, which is about `longtable`